# Inserting elements into sorted linked list in log(n)

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

Is it possible to insert an element into a sorted linked list in the right position without having to traverse thru it in O(n)?

I'm required to find the median and sum of the total of medians as elements are added into the list.

My implementation depends on a center handler which shifts around as items are being added but it is still too slow when dealing with datasets above 100000 (especially due to the insertion while loop).

Are there any other methods to solving this without a priority queue or BST?

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    long int data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};

class l_linked {
private:
    node *head, *tail, *center;
    int size = 0; 
    int left = 0, right = 0;


    void movePivot() {
        if (right > left && size%2) {
            center = center->next; // Move right
            right--;
            left++;

        }else if (right < left){
            center = center->prev; // Move right
            right++;
            left--;
        }

    }

public:

    void create_node (long int value) {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->data = value;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            // If list is empty, use temp as the head and tail. 
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            center = temp;
            temp = NULL; // set temp to reference NULL
            size++;
        }
    }

    l_linked () {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    int getSize () {
        return size;
    }

    long int getMedian () {
        if (size%2) {
            // odd number 
            //cout << center->data << endl;
            return center->data;
        }else {
            node* temp = new node;
            temp = center->next;
            //cout << "Even: " << center->data <<  endl;
            return ((center->data + temp->data)/2);
        }
    }


    void print () {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;  // set temp to reference the next node. 
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << center->data << endl;

    }

    void print_back() {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp = tail;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << " " ;
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << center->data << endl;
    }

    void insert_sort(long int input) {
        if (input > tail->data) {
            node *temp = new node;
            temp->data = input;
            temp->next = NULL;
            temp->prev = tail;
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
            size++;
            right++;
            movePivot();
            return;
        }
        else if (input < head->data){
            node *temp = new node;
            temp->data = input;
            temp->next = head;
            temp->prev = NULL;
            head->prev = temp;
            head = temp;
            size++;
            left++;
            movePivot();
            return;
        }
        // Function below seems to take up too much time 


        node *temp = new node; // Use this for traversal 
        node *insertion = new node; // Use this for insertion 
        insertion -> data = input;
        temp = head;
        int flag = 0;
        if (input > center->data) {
            temp = tail; // start from tail 
            flag = 1;
        }
        while (temp != NULL) {

            if (flag) {

                if (input > temp->data) {
                    insertion->prev = temp->prev;
                    insertion->next = temp;

                    temp->prev->next = insertion;
                    temp->prev = insertion;
                    size++;
                    if (insertion->data >= center->data) {
                        right++;
                        movePivot();
                        // Move up the pivot (upwards biased)
                    }
                    else if (insertion->data < center->data) {
                        left++;
                        movePivot();
                        // Move down the pivot 
                    }

                    return;
                }

                temp = temp->prev;

            }else {

                    if (input < temp->data) {
                        insertion->prev = temp->prev;
                        insertion->next = temp;

                        temp->prev->next = insertion;
                        temp->prev = insertion;
                        size++;
                        if (insertion->data >= center->data) {
                            right++;
                            movePivot();
                            // Move up the pivot (upwards biased)
                        }
                        else if (insertion->data < center->data) {
                            left++;
                            movePivot();
                            // Move down the pivot 
                        }

                        return;
                    }
                    temp = temp->next; // Traverse forward
            }
        }
    }


};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int numCase;
    cin >> numCase;
    clock_t start, end;

    for (int i = 0; i < numCase; ++i)
    {
        l_linked myList;
        int num;
        long int med = 0;
        cin >> num;

        int c = 0;
        /**
        for (int d = 0; d < num; ++d)
        {
            long int input;
            cin >> input;
            if (!d) {
                myList.create_node(input);
                med += myList.getMedian();
                continue;
            }
            myList.insert_sort (input);
            med += myList.getMedian();

        }
        */
        for (int d = 0; d < num; ++d)
        {
            start = clock();
            //long int input;
            //cin >> input;
            if (!d) {
                myList.create_node(rand() + 1);
                med += myList.getMedian();
                continue;
            }
            myList.insert_sort (rand() + 1);
            med += myList.getMedian();
            end = clock();
            if (((double)end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC > 0.001)
                cout << (((double)end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;


        }

        cout << med << endl;
        //myList.print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>


using namespace std;

int main () {
    int num, numCases;
    cin >> numCases;
    clock_t start, end;
    for (int d = 0; d < numCases; d++) {
        cin >> num;
        long int median = 0;
        long int center = 0;
        priority_queue<long int> q; // Left sub tree
        priority_queue<long int, std::vector<long int>, std::greater<long int> > q2; // Right sub tree

        start = clock();

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            long int number;
            //cin >> number;
            if (i == 0) center = rand();


            else if (number < center) {
                q.push(rand());
            }
            else if (number >= center) {
                q2.push(rand());

            }
            if (q2.size() > q.size() && (i+1)%2) {
                q.push(center);
                center = q2.top();
                q2.pop();
            } else if (q2.size() < q.size()){
                q2.push(center);
                center = q.top();
                q.pop();
            }

            if (i%2) {
                // if odd
                median += (center + q2.top())/2;
                continue;
            }

            median += (center);
            //cout << center << endl;
        }
        end = clock();

        cout << (((double)end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;

        cout << median << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've decided to use priority queues instead. This works at log(n)

Comment: No. That's the nature of a linked list.

Comment: Have you tried a std::vector and binary search? Big O isn't really relevant, the real runtime is.

Comment: Dont `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, it's a private non standard header not meant for includion.

Comment: You did enable the optimizer?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but `insert_sort()` leaks memory.  You have this line: `node *temp = new node; // Use this for traversal` followed a few lines later by `temp = head;`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a BST?

Comment: @MichaelBurr its kind of a restriction set by our tutor, we're only allowed to use what we've learnt so far and that's up to arrays (including vectors) and linked lists

Comment: @Wilson: You can employ a binary search on a sorted array/vector instead of using a linked list. I know that inserting into the middle of a vector will be O(n), but cache locality makes it way faster than a linked list anyway.

Comment: @AndyG hmm but binary search wouldn’t help me find a number smaller than the one I wanna insert tho. Cause it’ll be best if I can insert a number into the sorted vector at the right position. But even so shifting the rest of the elements upwards would be O(n)

Comment: @Wilson: Finding the first number that is not less than your number can be done in logarithmic time. See [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). My other point was that, yes, shifting them would be O(n), but due to the fact that the array is stored contiguously it's very cache friendly and its actual performance will surprise you tremendously.

Comment: @AndyG thanks seems like that’s the best resort apart from using priority queues. The dataset consist of numbers that are up to 10^9 up to 100000 numbers. Will have to find mid in under 1 second

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize a [skip list](https://brilliant.org/wiki/skip-lists/) structure for this problem. The way they work is, they offer some additional pointers to skip ahead of some parts of the list, in the form of additional layers. This increases space complexity but improves time complexity. With proper arrangements I think you should be able to reach O(logN) average complexity, however with still worst case O(N) complexity.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a data structure that still qualifies as a linked list. You should mention that the search complexity is log N in the average case, worst case remains O(n)

Comment: @AndyG I wouldn't say it qualifies as a linked list per se, otherwise `std::unordered_map` pretty much always will qualify as a linked list too

Comment: @PasserBy: Why not? It's defined by its use of a linked list with additional linked lists to make things faster.